# Function returns json instead of only values

Tags: json, powershell

I have ec2 instances with tags RDP, Test, etc.

I've created a function to make WinRM connection depending on a tag:

```
function PSconnector($IP){
# code to get instance tag
#....

if ($instance_tag -match 'RDP') {
   $user = "foo"
   $pass = "bar"
}
else{
  # donwload config
  #....

  $config = Get-Content .\$config_name| Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
  $user = $config.Server.ServerUser
  $pass = $config.Server.ServerPassword
}
# running echo to check only
echo $user
echo $pass
#
return ($user, $pass)
}
```

When I call it:

```
$creds =  PSconnector($ip)
$creds
```

For the RDP  - it is OK. But for the other:

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "Fri, 11 Jan 2019 09:56:53 GMT",
    "ContentLength": 2919,
    "ETag": "\"1f5ace2cfc81ba53ffde4b0e66cb65da\"",
    "ContentType": "application/json",
    "Metadata": {}
}
foobar
barfoo
```

In the same time echo in function shows correct varaibales, without json, only:

```
foobar
barfoo
```

**EDIT1**

Config downloaded using aws cli

```
 aws s3api get-object --bucket $bucket --key $key/$config_name $config_name
```

**EDIT2** 
If I use `Get-S3Object` instead the `aws cli` result is similar:

```
ETag         : "1f5ace2cfc81ba53ffde4b0e66cb65da"
BucketName   : jenkins-configuration-files
Key          : __json.config___
LastModified : 1/11/2019 11:56:53 AM
Owner        : Amazon.S3.Model.Owner
Size         : 2919
StorageClass : STANDARD

foobar
barfoo
```

Where is the issue?

Comment: I would guess in the bit we can't see: `# donwload config`

Comment: What is `$instance_tag` as it is not defined in your function. Perhaps you have a scope issue. Also the function will return the user and pass twice as function will return all output. Not just that from the return keyword. You might be seeing that issue with code you are `echo`ing. Echo being an alias for `write-output`

Comment: As you're getting `ETag` in the return I'd guess you're getting the file from S3? Look at this part of the code if so.

Comment: download config - `aws s3api get-object --bucket ...`
if I remove echo = result the same

Comment: Why not use `Get-S3Object`? Mixing cli and powershell isn't a great idea...

Comment: @JamesC. I've updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe `Read-S3Object` to `Out-Null` to stop the commands output being returned:

```
Read-S3Object -BucketName $bucket -Key $key/$config_name -File $config_name | Out-Null
```